# Footnote in Caption

Tags: footnotes

I am trying to place a footnote in a image caption. The footnote numer is showed but the footnote itself isn't placed in the bottom?

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
     \caption[Caption for LOF]{\footnote{s. 183}}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{rede/tabel.png}
  \end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

Comment: Do you want it at the bottom of the page or the bottom of the figure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont like to answer without having a MWE, but give it a try.

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
     \caption[Caption for LOF]{\footnotemark}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{rede/tabel.png}
  \end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}
\footnotetext{s. 183}
```

Comment: What do you mean by MWE?

Comment: Add a Minimal Working Example which is compileable so that others can play around.